# From Quarter-to-date data to daily values on bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a bq table that recieves data quarter to date per id

| id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 02/11/2022 |
| 2 | 70 | 02/11/2022 |
| 3 | 120 | 02/11/2022 |
| 1 | 150 | 01/11/2022 |
| 2 | 50 | 01/11/2022 |
| 3 | 100 | 01/11/2022 |

So each id got the cumulative data of the quarter
I need to create a view that takes each day's value minus the day's before per id

for id 1 (02/11 value minus 01/11 value, ...etc)

so the output should be like this

| id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 02/11/2022 |
| 2 | 20 | 02/11/2022 |
| 3 | 20 | 02/11/2022 |
| 1 | 150 | 01/11/2022 |
| 2 | 50 | 01/11/2022 |
| 3 | 100 | 01/11/2022 |

any help is really appreciated

Comment: Select `*, value - lag(value) over (partition by id order by date) from yourtable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might consider below query.

```sql
SELECT ID, date, 
       value - LEAD(value, 1, 0) OVER (
         PARTITION BY id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', date)) DESC
       ) AS new_value
  FROM sample_data;
```

**Query results**

[image]